# Split tuple items to separate variables

Tags: python, tuples, iterable-unpacking

I have tuple in Python that looks like this:

```
tuple = ('sparkbrowser.com', 0, 'http://facebook.com/sparkbrowser', 'Facebook')
```

and I want to split it, so that I can get every item from tuple independently in order to te able to do something like this:

```
domain = "sparkbrowser.com"
level = 0
url = "http://facebook.com/sparkbrowser"
text = "Facebook"
```

or similar to that. My need is to have every item separated. I tried with `.split(",") on tuple but I've gotten an error which says that tuple doesn't have a split option.

Comment: it's called [*sequence unpacking*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) (see last paragraph) or just *unpacking*.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Python can unpack sequences naturally.

```
domain, level, url, text = ('sparkbrowser.com', 0, 'http://facebook.com/sparkbrowser', 'Facebook')
```

Comment: I want to note this works for a list of tuples as well: `for a, b in [(a1, b1), (a2, b2)]`.

Answer (score 15):

Best not to use `tuple` as a variable name.

You might use `split(',')` if you had a string like `'sparkbrowser.com,0,http://facebook.com/sparkbrowser,Facebook'`, that you needed to convert to a list. However you already have a tuple, so there is no need here.

If you know you have exactly the right number of components, you can unpack it directly

```
the_tuple = ('sparkbrowser.com', 0, 'http://facebook.com/sparkbrowser', 'Facebook')
domain, level, url, text = the_tuple
```

Python3 has powerful unpacking syntax. To get just the `domain` and the `text` you could use

```
domain, *rest, text = the_tuple
```

`rest` will contain `[0, 'http://facebook.com/sparkbrowser']`

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> domain, level, url, text = ('sparkbrowser.com', 0, 'http://facebook.com/sparkbrowser', 'Facebook')
>>> domain
'sparkbrowser.com'
>>> level
0
>>> url
'http://facebook.com/sparkbrowser'
>>> text
'Facebook'
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative for this, is to use [**`collections.namedtuple`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). It makes accessing the elements of tuples easier.

**Demo:**

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Website = namedtuple('Website', 'domain level url text')
>>> site1 = Website('sparkbrowser.com', 0, 'http://facebook.com/sparkbrowser', 'Facebook')
>>> site2 = Website('foo.com', 4, 'http://bar.com/sparkbrowser', 'Bar')
>>> site1
Website(domain='sparkbrowser.com', level=0, url='http://facebook.com/sparkbrowser', text='Facebook')
>>> site2
Website(domain='foo.com', level=4, url='http://bar.com/sparkbrowser', text='Bar')
>>> site1.domain
'sparkbrowser.com'
>>> site1.url
'http://facebook.com/sparkbrowser'
>>> site2.level
4
```