# How can I separate and traverse data in a list of tuples in Python 2.6?

Tags: python, tuples, python-2.6

## Background

**Updated:** Here is [the horrendous list](http://textdump.net/read/6860/) I'm working with (please excuse the list's false title). The length and data is subject to change because I'm retrieving this information from an ever-changing database.

## Desired Outcome

I will further explain my purposes because I am unsure of the best way to go about this. Each number represents an ID **as noted below**. I need to create an XML file where Software elements have Target sub-elements based upon the SoftwareID and TargetID matching up in the tuple.

For example:

```
SoftwareID    TargetID                 XML Representation
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    65          115    <-- This Software element (id=65) has only one Target
                           sub-element (id=115)
    138         218    <-- This Software element (id=138) will have multiple
    138         219        Target sub-elements (ids=218, 219, 220)
    138         220
```

## Attempt

I've played with unpacking the sequence as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372952/python-split-tuple-items-to-single-stuff), but the list is much too long for this implementation. I get an **error** that says ***Too many values to unpack***. 
**I see now that this is actually a *list of tuples* instead of just a single tuple, so this wouldn't work anyway.**

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696027/split-elements-of-a-list-in-python) implementation but get an **error** that says ***tuple object has no attribute 'split'*.**

As for the rest of my implementation, I am lost without being able to separate this stupid list.

## Question

- How can I separate the data from this list of tuples in order to use it for
  the implementation described in the **Desired Outcome** section?

Comment: thats not a tuple ...

Comment: This looks like a list of tuples. Is this correct?

Comment: is that just a textfile with a tuple on each line? how is it input into your program

Comment: I layed it out like that for readability, but I suppose that was silly - I'll update the link to show what it actually looks like.

Comment: You get "Too many values to unpack." when you try to do something like `a, y = [1,2,3]`. You need as many variables as you have values in your container element (in my case 3) if you want to use tuple/list unpacking.

Comment: thats still not a tuple (its a list, that has tuples ...) but now we are splitting hairs

Comment: @JoranBeasley When I tried using `split()` on it, I get an error saying there is no `split()` function for tuple, which I suppose is why I thought it was a tuple. If it is in fact a list, could you explain why `split()` does not work?

Comment: split only works on strings .... I suspect you were trying to split an item in the list (the list contains tuples ... each tuple contains 2 elements)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Sorry, I should have specified - I used the implementatino found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696027/split-elements-of-a-list-in-python), which is when I got that error.

Comment: OK I have answered below as much as i am willing to for now

Comment: @JoranBeasley 10/10 am about to overhaul my question and make it less...incomprehensible? To the best of my abilities anyway -_-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its unclear what the actual problem is ... but maybe this will help resolve the issue

```
data = {}
for lhs,rhs in my_list_of_tuples:

    try:
        data[lhs].append(rhs)
    except KeyError:
        data[lhs] = [rhs]

print data.items()[:5]
```

to explain a little more simply lets look at it differently

```
my_list_of_tuples = [(1,2),(3,5),(7,8),(7,9)]
for item in my_list_of_tuples:
    #on first loop item=(1,2) ; 2nd loop item=(3,5); 3rd loop item=(7,8)
    left_number = item[0] 
    right_number = item[1]
    #these 2 lines can be simplified to
    left_number,right_number = item

    #now if left number is already in the data dictionary we will append the new right number to its list
    try:
        data[left_number].append(right_number)
    except KeyError: #: if the left_number is not already in our data dictionary
        data[left_number] = [right_number] #: create a new list that contains only the right number

#now that we are done we have data that maps left numbers to right numbers
print data
#{1:[2],3:[5],7:[8,9]}
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks a ton. My hope is that this will make creating my XML file much easier. I may edit your answer a little to get rid of the parts where you answered while my question was still confusing, if you don't mind me doing so

Comment: Eh, I'll just leave it. The rest could be useful to someone else. Thanks for the explanatory comments in the last piece by the way, not many people do that.