# Isolate multiple values from a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I have a python function which splits out multiple values for X, Y, and Z coordinates.
For example:

```
>>> sensor.acceleration
(2.4263221164, -1.0432706536, 9.5665047548)
```

What I need help with is assigning each of these values to a variable. To print these values I can do something like:

```
>>> print("X: %.2f, Y: %.2f, Z: %.2f" % (sensor.acceleration))
X: 2.43, Y: -1.01, Z: 9.58
```

But what I really need is how to set something like:

```
x_axis = 1st_value
y_axis = 2nd_value
z_axis = 3rd_value
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, split tuple items to single stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372952/python-split-tuple-items-to-single-stuff)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python we are allowed to do this ...

```
x_axis, y_axix, z_axis = sensor.acceleration
```